# How can I retrieve an IEnumerable<T2> from an IEnumerable<T1>?

Tags: c#, ienumerable

In `C#`, if I have an `IEnumerable<test>`, where the type `test` has a single property of type `test2`, how can I retrieve an `IEnumerable<test>` where each `test2` is filtered by a `bool` property.

Is the code something like this:

```
IEnumerable<T2> data = list.Select(x => x.obj && x.obj.isBool);
```

Here is a description of the objects:

```
public class test
{
    public test2 obj;
}

public class test2
{
    public bool isBool;
}
```

Comment: `return enumerableOfT.Select(t => t.T2Member)`, granted `T` has a generic constraint to `IHasT2Member`. Show some more relevant code if you want an actual answer.

Comment: You seem to be going for the "most confusing question" award. Please clarify what "type `T` is a single object of type `T2`" means as a starting point.

Comment: Can you please have a look at my code example?

Comment: So, can we assume that the `T` and `T2` are `test` and `test2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really just sounds like you need this:

```
IEnumerable<test2> data = list.Select(x => x.obj).Where(x => x.isBool);
```

Comment: Thank you. That is what I am looking for.